# Abstract fields in C# - adding set in a child class

Tags: c#, get, set, field, abstract

I am running into an issue with field inheritance.  First I will explain how I would like it to work, and then ask for suggestions on how I can change the syntax to do what I want.

Here's what I tried:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract D D1
    {
        get;
    }

    protected D _d2;
    public virtual D D2
    {
        get { return _d2; }
        set { _d2 = value; }
    }
}

public abstract class B : A
{
    protected D _d1;
    public override D D1
    {
        get { return _d1; }
        set
        {
            _d1 = value;
            Update();
        }
    }
}

public abstract class C : A
{
    public override D D1
    {
        get
        {
            return _d2.Find1();
        }
    }

    public override D D2
    {
        get { return base.D2; }
        set
        {
            base.D2 = value;
            Update();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that A doesn't compile because it can't find an method to override with D1's set.  This how I expected it to work:

```
A ab = new B();
print(ab.D1);
ab.D1 = 4; // I would expect a compiler error
((B)ab).D1 = 4; // I would expect a compiler error

A ac = new C();
print(ac.D1);
ac.D1 = 4; // I would expect a compiler error
((C)ac).D1 = 4; // **I would expect this to work**
```

One solution I can see would be to add "set;" to A1's D1 and throw a NotImplementedException if I try to use it in C, but that would prevent the issue from showing up in the compiler.  Anyone know of a way around this issue?  I would really like to keep them as fields so that I can display them using WPF.

Comment: Looks to me like your abstract A class requires a readonly implementation, and you wish to make it read/write; therefore, in your A class (and C class), make it read/write.  If you want the D1 property to be readonly only some of the time (bad design), you might consider using interfaces.

Comment: What is the compiler error that you are encountering?

Comment: @Jeremy What I would like to see is that B.D1 is read/write, but C.D1 is readonly because it is referred to by C.D2.  Is that at all possible?

Comment: @JGinSD Error '<B.D1>.set': cannot override because '<A.D1>' does not have an overridable set accessor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is with class `B`.  In class `A` you define `D1` as `public abstract D D1 { get; }`  However in `B` you are attempting to override `D1` and add a setter -- which is not defined by the abstract class.  You'll need to find another way to set the value in `B`.  If other classes need to be able to set `D1` then you may want to define `D1` as `public abstract D D1 { get; set; }`

If `B` only need to be able to set the value, just have it directly set the member value.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I decided to fix it by removing B.D1.set and adding a method B.SetD1(D value).  Now the question is... would C# be better if my syntax were allowed :)  I don't see a problem with being able to add a setter or getter to a field in a child class, as long as it can only be accessed when you know you're dealing with that class.

Comment: @hypehuman While it would be nice to be able to add a setter like you are trying unfortunately the language spec doesn't allow it for subclasses.  If you were using interfaces the adding of a setter to a get only property would be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Extending a property with a setter does not work with class inheritance; however, it works with interface implementation

```
public interface I
{
    int Prop { get; }
}

public abstract class A : I
{
    public abstract int Prop { get; protected set; }
    public abstract int Prop2 { get; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override int Prop
    {
        get;
        set; // ERROR: Cannot change accesibility here.
    }

    public override Prop2 { get; set; } // ERROR: Cannot add setter here.
}

public class C : I
{
    public int Prop { get; set; } // OK: Adding a setter works here.
}
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know that!  It wouldn't be ideal in my case because B and C share most of their logic.  Any idea why this isn't allowed with class inheritance?

Comment: Although not very elegant, you can use methods instead of properties. The base class would have a `public abstract int GetProp()` and the derived class would add a `public void SetProp(int value)`

Comment: Someone using the base class's property offering only a getter can assume that the property is readonly. If you could add a setter in a derived class, susbstituting an object of the derived class for an object of the base class could break the logic of a method assuming taht the peroperty is readonly! See: [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) on Wikipedia.